# Как можно заставить отображать несколько элементов DIV в одну строку?

Tags: css

```
<div class="uk-float-left">Текст</div>
<div class="uk-float-right">И текст</div>
```

Нужно что бы не происходило вот так: http://ssmaker.ru/3b1550a6.png
А было вот так: http://ssmaker.ru/ae44576a.jpg

Просто нужно что бы в случаи если текст не влазит он переносился, кто может помочь?

Comment: display: inline, display: inline-block. http://htmlbook.ru/css/display

Comment: @banme, все равно так как надо работать не хочет

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вижу проблему в том, что Ваш первый блок (на картинке, которой не должно происходить) слишком широкий, поэтому выталкивает второй блок на следующую строку всегда.
Надо найти способ держать первый блок в рамках дозволенного.
Один из вариантов - сделать табличку из div-ов.

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100px;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 100%;">asd adfksf kfkdf</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 1px;">=</div>
</div>
```

Последний div использует фиксированный размер. Но будет растягивать его, чтобы был виден полностью. Не более.
Первый с шириной в 100% займёт всё, что ему оставит блок с фиксированной шириной. Если не влезет, то вместо выталкивания следующего блока выполнит перенос собственного текста.
(В примере размер внешнего блока установлен в 100px как раз для демонстрации переноса текста.)

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно задать ширину каждому div, попробуй так в css

```
.uk-float-left,
.uk-float-right{
    width: 45%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`
ок, попробуй от центровать выравниванием,(в css со свойствами класса), вообщем крути в этом направлении))

Comment: Тот же эффект. ..

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?